# xcode 4.3.1 UITabBarController add more UIViewController

Tags: iphone

I am using Xcode 4.3.1

It is quite different from the old version.

If I ask Xcode create the Tabbed Application, it will create an UITabBarController with 2 tabbars.

How to add more UITabBar and related UIViewController?

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see how in your AppDelegate. You have to create manually more viewcontrollers and add them to the tabbar controller.